# Why I can't create repeated images and put these into an ImageView of my application?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-image

I am absolutly new in Android development and I have the followind doubt.

I have to draw images one next to each other into a Canvas object.

So let to do an example of what I neeed:

Into the **/res/drawable/** folder of my project I have this icon (I have resized it before put it into my project but I think that this is not so important):

[image]

So I have to put 3 of these icon one next to each other into a specific **ImageView** of my activity view (adding some white space between an image and the next one).

So I have done something like this:

1) This is the code of my **fragment_screen_slide.xml** file that represent the layout where these images have to be placed:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="@style/pastaTitleTextStyle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
                android:text="Difficoltà:" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/starContainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_height="250dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In particular these images have to be placed into this **ImageView** contained in the previous code snippet:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/starContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />
```

Here I have a first doubt because Androi Studio report an error on this line:

```
android:id="@+id/starContainer"
```

The reported error is a red underline on the **@** and when I pass the mouse pointer on it I can read the following error message:

```
<interface declaration>, <perceable declaration>, AidToken.import or AidTokenTye.package expected, got '@'
```

It seems strange to me because I am only creatin an id for the **ImageView** and because I have not problem when Gradle build the project.

Then, into the Java code that actually put the images into the previous **ImageView** I have done something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   System.out.println("PAGE NUMBER: "+ mPageNumber + 1);

   // Create the Canvas where the images are putted:
   Canvas difficultyCanvas = creaImgDifficulty();

    switch (mPageNumber + 1) {

    case 1:
        imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.carbonara);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.carbonara));

            difficultyCanvas = creaImgDifficulty();
            ImageView starContainer = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.starContainer);
            starContainer.draw(difficultyCanvas);

            break;

        // OTHER CASES
    }



    private Canvas creaImgDifficulty() {
        Canvas canvas;
        Bitmap chefHatOk = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.star);
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(output);

        int space = 10; // the space between images

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(chefHatOk, i * (chefHatOk.getWidth() + space), 0, null);
        }

        return canvas;
    }

}
```

So, as you can see in the previous code sippet, when the view is created first I create a new **Canvas** object (that contains the repeated images) calling the **creaImgDifficulty()** and then I try to draw this **Canvas** object into the previous **ImageView** having **id=starContainer**.

The **creaImgDifficulty()** create the **Canvas** object and draw the bitmap on it 3 times.

I obtain no error when I run the application but the images is not displayed into my **ImageView**.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: The `starContainer.draw()` call is drawing that `ImageView` to the `Bitmap` that's backing the `Canvas`. That's not what you want. Instead, you want to set the `Bitmap` that you drew on in `creaImgDifficulty()` as the image on the `ImageView`. You also want to make that `Bitmap` bigger than 1x1, which you currently have it at.

Comment: what do you exaclty mean that I also want to male that Bitmap bihher thaat 1x1? Please can you show me the code o what I have to do?

Comment: Your `createBitmap()` call is creating a `Bitmap` that's only 1 pixel by 1 pixel. Instead, you want it (3x the width of `chefHatOk` plus 2x `space`) wide, and (the height of `chefHatOk`) tall. Then the `output` `Bitmap` is what you set on the `ImageView`, with the `setImageBitmap()` method. You don't really want to return the `Canvas` from that method.

Answer (score 1):

XML cannot contain capitals. Switch your ID line to:

```
android:id="@+id/star_container"
```

Then change your java file references to match.